Example II.3.5 in Arithmetic of Elliptic curves
The example is
Let $C$ be a smooth curve, let $f \in \overline{K}(C)$ be a nonconstant function, and let $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ be the corresponding map (II.2.2). Then directly from the definitions, $$\tag{*} \operatorname{div}(f) = f^*((0)-(\infty)).$$
Where $f$ in (II.2.2) is
Let $C/K$ be a smooth curve and let $f\in K(C)$ be a function. Then $f$ defines a rational map, which we also denote by $f$,
$$ f(P)=\left\{
\begin{array}
?[f(P),1]\quad \text{if $f$ is regular at $P$,}\\
[1,0]\quad \text{if $f$ has a pole at $P$.}
\end{array}
\right.$$
I think that $(0) = [0,1]$ and $(\infty) = [1,0]$, hence we write $(*)$ as
$$
\operatorname{div}(f) = \sum_{P\in f^{-1}(0)} e_{f}(P) (P)-\sum_{P\in (1/f)^{-1}(0)} e_{1/f}(P)(P)
$$
by definition of $f^*$ ($f^*((Q)) = \sum_{P\in f^{-1}(Q)}e_f(P)(P)$).
Now I am stuck on finding the relationship between $e_f(P)$ and $\operatorname{ord}_P(f)$ to show that (*) is correct. (Or is there another way to show it?)

If you're stuck, a good way to begin to get unstuck would be to write down the definitions of $e_f(P)$ and $ord_P(f)$. Please add those to your post with an [edit].
